# Computing lengths for a rotating rod

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I know how to assign dimensions to a profile that is under static loading - that is under Mechanics of Materials, I would agree on a beam section, calculate the maximum moment and use the elasticity condition.

My question is, how would I do this on a rotating rod. How would I calculate the maximum moment, etc.

Ideally, I should be able to compute the force/torque distribution alongside the whole rotation and identify the maximum - then use the elasticity condition?

This is only a concept question, it's not my homework - and if anyone could suggest any reading material on this subject that would be awesome.

Consider the a rod of length *L*, mass *m*, some specific material and say a rectangular cross-section, rotating against some pin constraint A under the effect of some torque (electromotor?)

[image: sketch]

Comment: A rod rotating about its end, or a rod rotating about its axis, like a shaft? Either way there is not bending moment, but only axial and or radial stresses. Maybe a sketch can help clarify the _exact_ problem here.

Comment: Oh yes! How stupid of me. Of course there won't be developing any bending moments lol. Anyway, here's an [image I found on the internet that resembles the idea.](http://s3.amazonaws.com/answer-board-image/ff9ba11b-ef14-4168-af19-1377b6455cf1.jpeg)

Comment: If it is a massless rod then there will be no bending, but if the rod has mass moment of inertia then there will be bending.

Comment: Hi kklomit. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, please note that this isn't a homework or excercise question as I wrote above. Actually I still haven't got to a Dynamics course, which might be why I ask this question in the first place. [I found the picture](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/15lb-rod-pinned-end-angular-velocity-5-rad-s-horizontal-position-shown-figure-5-determine--q1738717), after searching on google for 'pinned rod', after a few unrelated pictures, finally I got one that had something to do with physics XD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a moving beam can be analyzed the same as a static beam, if the inertial forces are included. Consider the example you gave:

[image: sketch]

**Kinematics**

1. Track the center of mass starting from the position coordinates, and use chain rule of differentiation to get to velocity and acceleration.
   $$\begin{aligned}
    x &= \frac{\ell}{2} \cos \theta & y & = -\frac{\ell}{2} \sin \theta \\
   \dot{x} & = -\frac{\ell}{2}\dot{\theta} \sin\theta  & \dot{y} &= \frac{\ell}{2} \dot{\theta} \cos\theta  \\
   \ddot{x} &= -\frac{\ell}{2} (\ddot{\theta} \sin\theta + \dot{\theta}^2 \cos\theta) &
   \ddot{y} &= \frac{\ell}{2} (\dot{\theta}^2 \sin \theta - \ddot{\theta} \cos \theta)
   \end{aligned}$$

**Dynamics**

On the pivot *A* there are two forces acting $(A_x,A_y)$ and on the center of mass there is gravity $(0,-m g)$.

1. Sum of forces equals mass times acceleration of the center of mass. $$ \begin{aligned} A_x & = m \ddot{x}  & A_y - m g & = m \ddot{y} \end{aligned} $$
2. Sum of moments about the center of mass equals the mass moment of inertia times the rotational acceleration $$ A_y \frac{\ell}{2} \cos \theta + A_x \frac{\ell}{2} \sin \theta = I_z \ddot{\theta} $$ Remember that $\theta$ points in the negative $z$ axis and thus the a positive moment is considered clockwise.
3. The above three equations are solved for $A_x$, $A_y$, and $\ddot{\theta}$.
4. Now that the loading is defined, proceed like it is statics, but with the inertial loading at the center of mass of the segment considered. At a length $s=0\ldots \ell$ from the pivot the internal axial force $N(s)$, shear force $S(s)$ and moment $M(s)$ are
   $$ \begin{aligned}
   N(s) & = m g \left(\frac{s}{\ell}-1\right) \sin \theta + \frac{\ell}{2} m \dot{\theta}^2 \left( \frac{s^2}{\ell^2}-1\right) \\
   S(s) & = \dfrac{m g \left(1 - \frac{s}{\ell}\right) \left( I_z - \frac{s}{\ell} \left( \frac{\ell}{2} \right)^2\right) \cos \theta }{I_z + m \left( \frac{\ell}{2} \right)^2} \\
   M(s) & = \dfrac{\frac{\ell}{2}mg\left(1-\frac{s}{\ell}\right)\left(I_{z}\left(\frac{s}{\ell}-1\right)-m\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^{2}\right)\cos\theta}{I_{z}+m\left(\frac{\ell}{2}\right)^{2}}
   \end{aligned} $$
5. Now you can use the axial+bending stress formula $$\sigma_x = \frac{N(s)}{A} + \frac{M(s) h }{I_{xx}}$$

<sup>NOTE:</sup> Dynamics of beams use both the *mass* moment of inertia $I_z =\int r^2 {\rm d}m$ and the section *area* moment of inertia $I_{xx}=\int r^2 {\rm d}A$

As you can see as soon as you start considering motion with beams, it becomes a *very* complex problem very fast. Also note that you find the peak bending moment near $s=\frac{2}{3} \ell$ which is interesting on its own.

Answer (score 0):

If your rod is a pendulum that was initially held horizontal by a force at the free end, before release it was a beam like you know how to calculate.  It wouldn't be quite straight, it would sag in the middle, creating stress and strain.  When you release it, each small piece of the rod is acted on by gravity and the stresses in the rod, and accelerates under the forces it feels.  A good approximation would be that the CM undergoes the usual pendulum motion and the rod vibrates in curvature at its natural frequency.  In fact, the static bend will not match the fundamental mode shape.  You could resolve the static bend into the various mode shapes and consider each one to vibrate at its natural frequency.

If the rod rotates at a constant rate in a horizontal plane, there is no torque supplied by the motor.  It will have the usual sag from a fixed end/open end rod and some radial stress from centrifugal force.